# How to install SSL Certs for tomcat keystore

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, ssl, https

I am trying to setup SSL for tomcat. Following the below linked instructions, I ran the command:

```
keytool -genkey -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keystore keystore_name -keysize 2048
```

Instructions: https://knowledge.verisign.com/support/ssl-certificates-support/index?page=content&actp=CROSSLINK&id=AR227

That generated the tomcat.keystore file. I generated the csr file using the above instructions as well and used it to request a SSL certificate from godaddy. They generated the .crt files and I downloaded them. I then tried to import them using:

http://www.sslshopper.com/tomcat-ssl-installation-instructions.html

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias (root/intermediate/tomcat) -file (root.crt, intermediate.crt, primary.crt) -keystore tomcat.keystore
```

I notice in the ssl installation instructions they specify "-keystore keystore.key", as opposed to the "tomcat.keystore" file I specify. Where do I get the .key file or will the .keystore file work the same? I import the .crt files, but the ssl cert doesn't get updated. It still shows as an unverified cert that expires in 3 months opposed to the 2 years that the godaddy ssl cert is valid for. Any ideas on why the imports would not work properly? The server is running CentOS 6.5 and Tomcat version 7.0.50 if that has any bearing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some more digging, it turns out the problem I was having was that for the import of the Primary cert, the alias name provided must be exactly the same as the one used when generating the csr. I imported the certs again using the correct alias name and now the cert is recognized properly.